# finding the path of place that error happened in C# pages

Tags: c#

I want to put a method in Catch {} which send the error to my ".log" file. 
I like to put the address of the page and the method that the error happened their. so I want you to help me and tell me that how I can define "strErrorPath" and put it as on of my method input .

```
 public static void SendErrorToPersonalErrorMessage(Exception ex,string strErrorPath )
{
    string strErrorMEssage = string.Format("Error:{0} Time:{1:yyy/mm/dd - hh:mm:ss},Address:{2}", ex.Message, System.DateTime.Now, strErrorPath);
    System.IO.StreamWriter oStreamWriter = null;
    string strPersonalErrorMEssagePath = "~/App_Data/Log/PersonalErrorMessage.log";
    string strPersonalErrorMessagePathName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strPersonalErrorMEssagePath);
    oStreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strPersonalErrorMessagePathName, true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: I wanted this to figure out those errors that would happen in c# classes in  namespace : tools for ASP.NET Web Form . was it important?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ex.Source` and `ex.StackTrace` they will show useful information about the exception.

You can read more about `StackTrace` [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are welcome bro. Is that what you are looking for. Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using Caller Info Attribute.
Here is the reference  : [MSDN : Caller Information (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653988.aspx)

```
public static void Log(string errMsg,
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string member = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string filePath = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLine = 0)
    {
        //log somthing...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try that :

```
        try
        {
            // your code...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string strErrorPath = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            SendErrorToPersonalErrorMessage(e, strErrorPath);
        }
```